# Is there a Core Data predicate for all objects in a linked list?

Tags: core-data, linked-list, predicate

Is there a way to formulate a Core Data predicate for a given object, representing the head of a singly linked list, and all of the other objects in that list?

E.g., I have objects, each of which has a relationship to another object (say `nextObject`) and I want a predicate for a specified object and all other objects reachable by traversing `nextObject` (until it is `nil`).

*CLARIFICATION*:

I'm using these for a `UITableView`'s `NSFetchedResultsController`, so these need to be part of the fetch, not something I iterate through in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use a predicate for a linked list. Instead, you would just start with the first object of interest and walk the relationships by calling `nextObject` until you hit one that did not have a `nextObject` value.

You can find the first and last objects with a predicate in a fetch just by looking for `previousObject==nil` and `nextObject==nil`.

Predicates do not understand arbitrarily long relationship chains. They understand a chain like `enity1.entity2.entity3` but not `nextObject.nextObject.nextObject...` because they have no way of knowing when to stop.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my initial question: I'm using these for a UITableView's NSFetchedResultsController, so these need to be part of the fetch, not something I iterate through in code.

Comment: Predicates evaluate to boolean expressions so you really can't have a true or false statement about a linked list. The ordering is arbitrary so there is nothing to test. The nextObject is just the nextObject.